# ASP.NET applications scalability best practices guide

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, scalability

Is there are a guide published by microsoft or somebody else about the best practices for creating scalable web applications? like patterns to use and how to do data access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best advice I can give is to do these three things (roughly in order):

1. Avoid unnecessary postbacks
2. Avoid excessive viewstate
3. Spend your time optimizing your database

Comment: What about using linqdatasources to bind to controls, is that bad or good?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, as long you fit it in the points above: does it cause extra postbacks - does it cause viewstate (hint: viewstate is independent of data source), and can you optimize your db code when the time comes (my experience with linq is that you usually can).

Comment: Coming back to this years later, I'll add: **4. Avoid unnecessary memory allocations.**

Answer (score 3):

[The Microsoft Patterns & Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) group is a good one stop shopping ground for that.

**Edit:** Here is their guide specifically on [Scalability and Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998530.aspx?rssCatalog). [Chapter 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx) includes information specific to ASP.NET Performance and [Chapter 17](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998583.aspx) includes information about Tuning.

Comment: Specifically chapter 6 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx) and 17 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998583.aspx) for ASP.Net.

Comment: @adrianbanks - Edited the main answer with you specific links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent article on the subject of scale:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx  Which basically discusses the issues of load balancing, session affinity and caching all of which become important in any scaling discussion.  If you have a specific question after that, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a read through the [MVC Storefront series](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/).  It's ASP.NET MVC based, but demonstrates a nice approach for creating a loosely-coupled, well architected website.  You could easily apply most of the principles to a webforms site as necessary (though I'd recommend going with MVC if yo have the choice...)